# Multiple testing correction for multiple 2-way anova testings

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, repeated-measures, post-hoc, bonferroni

I run two-way mixed ANOVAs to examine the effect of factorA (between-subject factor: 3 levels) and factorB (within-subject factor: 2 levels) on outcome variables. I then perform simple effect analysis (2 one-way anova for each level of factorB) and report Bonferroni-adjusted post hoc tests. Here are an example of my results.

The mixed ANOVA results for *outcome1* showed that the main effects of factorA (F(2, 85) = 6.048, p = 0.004, ηp2 = 0.125) and factorB (F(1, 85) = 14.078, p < 0.001, ηp2 = 0.142) were significant. In addition, there was a significant interaction (F(2, 85) = 5.616, p = 0.005, ηp2 = 0.117). We then performed simple effect analysis. For the low level of factorB, outcome1 was significantly different among the three factorA conditions (F(2, 85) = 6.02, p = 0.004, ηp2 = 0.124), with Bonferroni-adjusted post hoc tests showing that outcome1 in the conditionA was significantly larger than that in the control condition (M = 4.276 > M = 0.667, p = 0.006).

Further, I have ran 2 above two-way ANOVAs, to test the IVs' effects on two similar outcome variables. Should I do a Bonferroni Correction again (i.e., use current p-value*2) for the multiple two-way anova results. And if so, *should I use current p-value*2 for all reported p-values (including the main effects of factorA and factorB, and their interaction, *e.g., (F(2, 85) = 6.048, p = 0.004*2, ηp2 = 0.125*)*, or *should I only need to use current p-value*2 for post hoc tests of one-way anova*, i.e., (M = 4.276 > M = 0.667, p = 0.006*2)?

Thank you very much, and I much appreciate your kind help!

Comment: current p-value*2